# iframe sandbox allow-same-origin

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, sandbox, same-origin-policy

I have the following iframe definition :

```
<iframe id="super-frame" 
sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts 
allow-forms allow-top-navigation 
allow-pointer-lock 
allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation">
</iframe>
```

Basically, I just want to block all "alert" popups from the iframe while allowing everything else.

THE ISSUE:

The page from mydomain.com/abc/page1.html loads mydomain.com/abc/page2.html into the iframe noted above.  Then, whenever links with target of _parent are clicked in page2.html to go to say page3.html page4.html etc, Chrome browser does not allow this to happen saying it is cross origin!

So, not sure what the issue is with the definition of iframe. If anyone has come across similar situation and know of a fix, please let me know.  Note that this is on latest chrome version on mac.

Thank You.